# Regex for sports score in Java

Tags: java, regex, string

Good Evening all,

I am looking to extract a sports score from a string of text in Java, including the nouns either side of the score.

A string of text, most likely a summary describing a particular match, may read “[ANY TEXT]France 0-0 Germany[ANY TEXT]” where [ANY TEXT] may refer to any string of text which can include characters, special symbols and numeric values provided these are not in the form of [0-9]-[0-9] or [0-9] – [0-9]

For example the string “In the 7.45 kick-off the final score was France 2-3 Germany, a good game!” would return the output:

France 2-3 Germany

Likewise, noting the space characters, the string “In the 7.45 kick-off the final score was France 2 - 3 Germany, a good game!” would return the output:

France 2 - 3 Germany

This is what I have so far:

```
import java.util.regex.*;
public class Regex {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str="Current score is France 0-0 Germany"; 
        Pattern pat = Pattern.compile("REGEX NEEDED HERE")
        Matcher m = pat.matcher(str); 

         while( m.find() ) { 
         System.out.println(m.group(..)); 
         }
    }
}
```

Required Output: France 0-0 Germany

Please let me know what regular expression / regex I should use here to obtain the desired output, preferably with the full code?

Comment: Have you even looked up simple Regex tutorials? This really isn't very hard.

Comment: BTW, that's a perfect scenario for TDD. Start with a really simple scenario and write a single test, code it green. Increase complexity from test to test.

Comment: How about `United States 1 - 0 People's Republic of China`? How do you decide if `United` is part of the country name or part of the text to ignore?

Comment: Or `USA 1-0 China`?  Scraping facts (like football scores) from natural language text using regexes is never going to be reliable.

Comment: @StephenC - Would you have any suggestions to offer on how better to do this in that case?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amazon_Mechanical_Turk.  Seriously.  This is one of those problems where the best thing to do is to change the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regex to find the game result is `France\s+\d+-\d+\s+Germany`

In Java code it is used as

```
  String str="Current score is France 0-0 Germany"; 
  Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("France\\s+\\d+-\\d+\\s+Germany").matcher(str);

  while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group(0));
  }
```

See [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/oC9hI3/2) for description

Comment: What if I wanted "France" and "Germany" to be any single word with a space either side? 

For example:
[any string of text]\\s[TeamName1]\\s+\\d+-\\d+\\s[TeamName2]